# HTTP communication on port other than 80?

Tags: http, server, port

In the book **Computer Networking: A top down approach** second edition by *Kurose*, in chapter 2 under Building a Web Server (2.8),

Author creates a server listening on the port 6789 for HTTP responses. Following was the URL given

> http://somehost.somewhere.edu:6789/somefile.html

But if port 80 is the reserved port for HTTP communication, how is this server working? Wouldn't the HTTP responses be directed to port 80 while our server listens on a completely different port?

Any help in understanding/clarifying this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried it and seen it fail? If you haven't seen it fail, you don't have an "actual problem that you face" [as our rules require](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Where should I be asking these? Stack exchange network engineering is i guess too hardcore for this question. I couldn't even find a tag for "port"! @CharlesDuffy

Comment: I'm not saying don't ask questions about this topic at all. I'm saying try to follow the instructions (try running a HTTP server on a non-80 port!), and _then_ ask if you have an actual problem (so you can show code you attempted, symptoms of the failure, &c). Assuming that problem is _about code_, that is; if you're just running code someone else wrote, that's more a general-computing question for [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: I'm going to flag this for transfer to server fault, rather than Super User. Also, I looked at book, and 2.8 doesn't cover the topic you described. 

In short, "reserved" means, don't run another type of server (for example: SMTP) on this port.

Comment: @benc Not sure which version of book you referring to, mine is given at 2.8

Answer (score 2):

Port 80 is reserved to be the **default** port for HTTP, but when the client uses `:6789` in the optional port field of the URL, it's overriding that default and forcing port 6789 to be used instead.

Comment: (Answering community wiki because I don't believe the question to be on-topic)